# Why is the of date undefined when my typescript interface is a union type of Date or null

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface like:

```
interface Props {
   readonly date: Date | null;
}
```

How is it possible that my console output shows undefined when the type only allows for a Date or null value?

```
const MyTimestamp = ({date}: Props) => {
   console.log("date=" + date);  // outputs undefined
}
```

Comment: Are you passing a value for `date` when you call `MyTimestamp`?

Answer (score 3):

Because Typescript != Javascript.

Your Javascript `console.log` logs the value `date` at run time. Javascript doesnt know types, like Typescript, so `date` can be anything.
Typescript is only for you. To help you write "cleaner" code.